# Помогите решить проблему с подключением статичних файлов NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend

**Помогите подключить стили в мой nodejs проект, метод app.use(express.static('assets')) не работает**
**Вилезает ошибка в консоле: GET 'http://localhost:3000/assets/css/style.css' net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)**
вот мой путь к файлам

```
node_modules
html-views
assets
  css
    style.css
  js
   app.js
server.js
package.json
```

Вот мой код:

```
// import express
const express = require('express')

// import path
const path = require('path')

// initialization of server
const app = express()

// create PORT
const PORT = 3000

// createPath function
const createPath = (page) =>
  path.resolve(__dirname, 'html-views', `${page}.html`)

// middlewares
// middleware for styles
// app.use(express.static('assets'))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets'))

// main route
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(createPath('index'))
})

// posts route
app.get('/posts', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(createPath('posts'))
})

// post route
app.get('/posts/id:', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(createPath('post'))
})

// add post route
app.get('/add-post', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(createPath('add-post'))
})

// error midleware
app.use((request, response) => {
  response.status(404).sendFile(createPath('error'))
})

// start server
app.listen(PORT, (error) => {
  error ? console.log(error) : console.log(`Listening port ${PORT}`)
})
```

Comment: `app.use(express.static(__dirname))`?

Comment: @nörbörnën - Спасибо, помогло, а можете подсказать если мне нужно отдельную папку с файлами. то как решить проблему

Comment: `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets'))` и заменить `http://localhost:3000/assets/css/style.css` на `http://localhost:3000/css/style.css`